# saving and retrieving values from session state in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reviewing some web code and I am not exactly sure how ASP.net session state works. Any helps would be gratefully appreciated.

If a User object is saved to the session state during login, and User.FirstName and User.LastName is set. If other web pages retrieve the user object from the session and set the FirstName to something else is that persisted on other web pages? Or, do you need to re-add the user object back to the session once it has been modified? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Session is persisted on the server, but *tracked* via the client. I repeat - via the client.

In most cases, sessions are tracked with cookies. So using your example, when User object is saved to Session:

```
Session["UserInfo"] = new User { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs" };
```

A cookie will be sent to the client with a unique identifier. This cookie is passed along to all further HTTP requests from this client/browser unless it expires.

If another user comes along (from a different machine) for the first time, `Session["UserInfo"]` will be null.

An alternative to cookies is "cookieless-session" - where instead of using a cookie to store the session identifer - the identifier is tacked onto the URL.

So the answer is no - other web pages (e.g other clients/machines/browsers) will not have access to this information.

If you want information shared between different clients from the web server, use **Cache**.

However given the context of the question (User information), it is valid to store this information in the Session, as it is only relevant to a particular user (shouldn't be shared).

An alternative a lot of people use instead of sticking the User info in the session, is to put it in a generic principle which get's attached to the Forms Authentication ticket.

Up to you which road you choose.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get your head around Sessions in ASP.Net

<strike>http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx</strike>
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 1):

Any changes you make to the object are persisted.

Comment: OK, so if on my page I retrieve my user object via the session and set my page level user variable. If I update the user object via the page level variable, it will automatically update the session user object?

Comment: Yes. Unless your app is running on a server farm, your session data is just an object held in server memory (inproc). ASP.NET figures out which client a request is coming from by an id, then uses that ID to make sure the right session dictionary is the code handling the request, but it doesn't *alter* the dictionary. Any changes you make to it or any objects it points to persist.